# Code composer studio Content assist

Tags: c, eclipse, content-assist

I have a problem with the content assist of code composer studio v.7.2. The problem is that it fills out methods with its prototyped method/function arguments.

```
foo(int someint,double somedouble){...}
```

when i then in code composer start writing foo and press Ctrl + Space and then select the suggested completion it will complete to this:

```
foo(int someint,double somedouble){Cursor position is here?}
```

this is really annoying hope you guys can help.

Comment: Go to `Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Content Assist->Templates` and check there.

Comment: To answer my own question. The solution were to just roll back to CCS 6.1.3. 
In the version 6 the default behaviour is as expected.